# Reformulating the definition of injectivity

Tags: logic

So injectivity is usually described as:

$$
\forall y \in Y. \forall x_1, x_2 \in X. x_1 R y \wedge x_2 R y \Rightarrow x_1 = x_2
$$

But I would like to reformulate this, starting with $x_1 \neq x_2 \Rightarrow ...$, and I feel like this would be correct:

$$
\forall y \in Y. \forall x_1, x_2 \in X. x_1 \neq x_2 \Rightarrow x_1 R y \oplus x_2 R y
$$

But even though this reads correct to me, it feels to me what I did is imply from $A \Rightarrow B$ that $\neg A \Leftarrow \neg B$, which I don't think I can do...

EDIT:

Okay, so coming from the answer I got I will just correct myself.
I wrote $x_1 \neq x_2 \Rightarrow x_1 R y \oplus x_2 R y$. This is wrong, but $x_1 \neq x_2 \Rightarrow \neg (x_1 R y \wedge x_2 R y)$ or $x_1 \neq x_2 \Rightarrow x_1 \not R y \vee x_2 \not R y$ is correct.

Comment: Inferring $\lnot B \Rightarrow \lnot A$ from $A \Rightarrow B$ is fine, but what do you mean by $\oplus$?

Comment: Exclusive or. I thought this was a common convention

Comment: $\oplus$ for exclusive or is a common convention. I just wanted you to confirm what you meant, as it invalidates what you you have written. $\lnot (C \land D)$ is not equivalent to $C \oplus D$ (as you can see if you consider the case when $C$ and $D$ are both false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It feels to me what I did is imply from $A \Rightarrow B$ that $\neg A \Leftarrow \neg B$, which I don't think I can do.

This is called the $\it contrapositive$ of $A \Rightarrow B$, and yes, you can do it. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)